# Simplify if else condition ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a if else condition in my ruby code listed below:

```
if !category.nil?
  return false unless company_matches.any? { |w|
                      comparison = /(\s|^)#{w}(\s|$)/i
                      (title.index(comparison) || description.index(comparison) || clean_title.index(comparison) || clean_desc.index(comparison)) && (category == 'Business')}
else
  return false unless company_matches.any? { |w|
                      comparison = /(\s|^)#{w}(\s|$)/i
                      (title.index(comparison) || description.index(comparison) || clean_title.index(comparison) || clean_desc.index(comparison))}
end
```

How can i simplify this to make it look more subtle?

Comment: Isn't the first one just the second one with `&& (category == 'Business')` at the end?

Comment: Yup I need to remove the repeating condition.

Comment: you can create a `private_method` to handle the repetition.

Comment: Can the `company_matches` contain spaces?

Comment: Btw as a rule of thumb, avoid double negatives. Even more so - quadruple negatives.

Comment: Why do you want to make it look more subtle? Code should be the exact opposite of subtle, it should be obvious and clear. Are you asking about obfuscation? What, *exactly* do you mean by "subtle"? What is your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
company_matches.any? do |company|
  [title, description, clean_title, clean_desc].any? do |attribute|
    attribute.match? /(\s|^)#{company}(\s|$)/i
  end && (category == 'Business' || category.nil?)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to do your comparisons so you don't repeat yourself. You can also abstract the `comparison` variable out of the `if .. else` block. Here's what I have:

```
comparison = /(\s|^)#{w}(\s|$)/i 
result = perform_comparison(title, description, clean_title, clean_desc, comparison)   

unless category.nil? 
  return false unless company_matches.any? { |w| result && (category == 'Business')}
else
  return false unless company_matches.any? { |w| result }
end

# somewhere else in your code
def perform_comparison(title, description, clean_title, clean_desc, comparison)
  title.index(comparison) || description.index(comparison) || clean_title.index(comparison) || clean_desc.index(comparison)
end
```